# MAUI: How to draw image from byte[] on MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, maui, maui-windows

I'm try to use maui develop an application now, but I meet a problem:

MAUI document just offers the way to draw the image from a file, link is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/graphics/draw?view=net-maui-7.0#draw-an-image

In my scenario, I will get the yuv/rgb byte[], not the image file, but the PlatformImage just can create the IImage object from an image file that has been encoded. And ICanvas just needs to use IImage object to draw an image.
And PlatformImage isn't support Windows.

```
using Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Platform;
...

IImage image;
Assembly assembly = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("GraphicsViewDemos.Resources.Images.dotnet_bot.png"))
{
    image = PlatformImage.FromStream(stream);
}

if (image != null)
{
    canvas.DrawImage(image, 10, 10, image.Width, image. Height);
}
```

So, my question is, is there any way to draw the byte[] into View?

I have tried Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Skia, but it cannot work.

This is my codes:

```
// Licensed to the .NET Foundation under one or more agreements.
// The .NET Foundation licenses this file to you under the MIT license.

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection.Metadata;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Skia;
using Render.Source;
using SkiaSharp;

namespace MauiSample
{
    internal class VideoDrawable : IDrawable, IDisposable
    {
        private SKBitmap? _sKBitmap;
        private SkiaImage? _skiaImage;
        private Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.IImage? _image;
        private uint _width;
        private uint _height;
        private byte[]? _buffer;

        public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)
        {
            if (_image is null)
            {
                return;
            }
            canvas.DrawImage(_image, dirtyRect.X, dirtyRect.Y, dirtyRect.Width, dirtyRect.Height);
        }

        private void EnsureBitmap(uint width, uint height)
        {
            bool needResize = false;
            if (_width != width)
            {
                needResize = true;
                _width = width;
            }
            if (_height != height)
            {
                needResize = true;
                _height = height;
            }
            if (_sKBitmap is null)
            {
                _sKBitmap = new SKBitmap((int)width, (int)height, SKColorType.Rgb888x, SKAlphaType.Premul);
            }
            else if (needResize)
            {
                _sKBitmap.Resize(new SKImageInfo((int)width, (int)height), SKFilterQuality.None);
            }
            if (_skiaImage is null)
            {
                _skiaImage = new SkiaImage(_sKBitmap);
                _image = _skiaImage;
            }
            else if (needResize)
            {
                _skiaImage.Resize(width, height);
            }
            if (needResize)
            {
                _buffer = new byte[width * height << 2];
            }
        }

        public void DrawVideoFrame(byte[] yuvFrame, uint width, uint height)
        {
            EnsureBitmap(width, height);
            byte[] pixels = new byte[width * height * 4];
            VideoFrameConverter.YUV2RGBA(yuvFrame, pixels, width, height);
            unsafe
            {
                fixed (byte* p = pixels)
                {
                    _sKBitmap.SetPixels((nint)p);
                }
            }
        }

        #region IDisposable

        private bool _disposed = false;

        // Use C# finalizer syntax for finalization code.
        // This finalizer will run only if the Dispose method
        // does not get called.
        // It gives your base class the opportunity to finalize.
        // Do not provide finalizer in types derived from this class.
        ~VideoDrawable()
        {
            // Do not re-create Dispose clean-up code here.
            // Calling Dispose(disposing: false) is optimal in terms of
            // readability and maintainability.
            Dispose(disposing: false);
        }

        // Implement IDisposable.
        // Do not make this method virtual.
        // A derived class should not be able to override this method.
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(disposing: true);
            // This object will be cleaned up by the Dispose method.
            // Therefore, you should call GC.SuppressFinalize to
            // take this object off the finalization queue
            // and prevent finalization code for this object
            // from executing a second time.
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        // Dispose(bool disposing) executes in two distinct scenarios.
        // If disposing equals true, the method has been called directly
        // or indirectly by a user's code. Managed and unmanaged resources
        // can be disposed.
        // If disposing equals false, the method has been called by the
        // runtime from inside the finalizer and you should not reference
        // other objects. Only unmanaged resources can be disposed.
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            // Check to see if Dispose has already been called.
            if (!_disposed)
            {
                // If disposing equals true, dispose all managed
                // and unmanaged resources.
                if (disposing)
                {
                    // Dispose managed resources.
                    _skiaImage.Dispose();
                    _sKBitmap.Dispose();
                }

                // Note disposing has been done.
                _disposed = true;
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Refer this: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/6888

Answer (score 0):

there is ByteArrayToImageSource converter. Here is link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/converters/byte-array-to-image-source-converter
It can be used like this:

```
<Image Source={Binding byteArray, Converter={converters:ByteArrayToImageSource}}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the byte[] stream array, you can save it into a MemoryStream

```
var imageMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(_buffer);
```

after that you can load the image from the stream with

```
ImageSource image = ImageSource.FromStream(() => imageMemoryStream);
```

Note that this is an ImageSource-type value.